# Matte effect in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, effects

I'm new to graphic design.

Does anyone know how to create a the matte shape like this from the picture below![image]

Answer (score 2):

It is possible using Illustrator and using the photoshop effect built in illustrator..
please follow the following steps.

1. place you image in your artboard.
2. copy `[CTRL+C]` the placed image and past it exactly on the old on by pressing `[CTRL+F]` - now you have two images over each other.
3. draw a circle over the desire spot.
4. by the black arrow select the circle and the image that you have just pasted over the old one. and make a clipping mask by going to `object>clipping mask>make` or press `[CTRL+7]`
5. now we are ready to make the effect to the circle which appear exactly on the old image spot. be careful not to move it. go to `effect>blur>Gaussian blur` and set a desire value preferable to be between 3 to 7
6. after doing the effect group the circle with the old placed image by selecting them both and press `[CRTL+G]`

[image]

if you want to make the matte effect you can add another circle with a white color having 50% opacity and put over or under the mask circle.

[image]

that's it.